# Firebase Firestore - 2 queries Promise All

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to generate a few fake profiles for development, Im using a predefined json dataset and I cant seem to get it to work, I want to create the accounts using a given email and password then use other data in the same json dataset to create user profiles in a collection under their uid. Im trying to user promise all but all that gets created is the authenticated user in firebase but not the populated users collection with the remaining data. my function looks like this so far:

```
  doSignupFAKEUSERS( users: any ) {

  users.forEach( usr => {

  firebase.default.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword( usr.email, usr.password ).then( (result) => {

          const added = this.afs.collection<any>("users").doc(result.uid).set({
              email:usr.email,
              pw: usr.password,
              uid: result.uid,
              age: usr.age,
              displayName: usr.email.substring(0, usr.email.indexOf("@")),
              photoURL: usr.photoURL,
              currentCity: usr.currentCity,               
            })

            return Promise.all([result, added]);    

      });

    })    
}
```

and this is my test data

```
    account: [{ displayName: string, age: number, email: string, photoURL: string, uid: string,  currentCity: string }] = [
    {
        displayName: 'Albert Cruz',
        age: 23,
        email: 'albert.cruz15@example.com',
        photoURL: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/95.jpg',
        currentCity: 'Prague',
        uid: ''
    } ,
    {
        displayName: 'Albert Wheeler',
        age: 26,    
        email: 'albert.wheeler22@example.com',
        photoURL: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/40.jpg',
        currentCity: 'Prague',    
        uid: ''
    }      

    ];
```

Comment: ```Promise.all()``` takes an array of promises. It looks like ```added``` might be a promise, but it doesn't look like ```result``` is

Answer (score 0):

Since users is an array you can map it into promises and pass that as argument to `Promise.all`:

```
doSignupFAKEUSERS(users: any) {
  return Promise.all(
    users.map(usr => {
          firebase.default.auth().
          createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usr.email, usr.password)
          .then((result) => {
            return this.afs.collection<any>("users").doc(result.uid).set({
              email: usr.email,
              pw: usr.password,
              uid: result.uid,
              age: usr.age,
              displayName: usr.email.substring(0, usr.email.indexOf("@")),
              photoURL: usr.photoURL,
              currentCity: usr.currentCity,
            })
          });      
        })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but its still not firing the second then to add to the users collection, it only adds the first user

Comment: @Kravitz are you catching the error? `.then(happy).catch(not so happy)` If you console.log before calling firebase.default.auth are the 2 users passed to function to begin with?